# Visualize changes other time

Tags: visualization, tools

I am analyzing a population movement pattern and I would like to design a visualization like this one:

[image: Desired sample data visualization.]

Is there any *tool* or *language* (preferably R) I can use for that purpose?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gidutndki3oepl1/Graphs_SK.xlsx?dl=0) is a sample of my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can reproduce that graph with some `ggplot`!

[image]

Here is the code to create it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- read.csv2('Graphs_SK.csv')    

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Governorate)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = Mid.May.2015, yend = Dec.16, xend = Governorate),
               color = 'grey', size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Mid.May.2015, color = 'start'), size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Dec.16, color = 'end'), size = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = '(Population in millions)', 
                      labels = c('May 2015', 'Dec 2016'), 
                      values = c('start' = 'steelblue4', 'end' = 'steelblue')) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, name = '', position = 'top') +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle('1 Year of something of Governorate') +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = 'right')) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        legend.position = c(-.15, 1.03),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        legend.justification = c(0, 0),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = NA), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

Comment: when I use Source or Source with Echo to run the script does not produce the plots. Even when I select the whole script with Ctrl+A, then Run the current line or selection (Ctrl+Enter) the does not produce the plot. Any clue? Thank you.  Here is a PrtScn:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2po7hd54f85om0/ggplots.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Type `p` or `print(p)` in the console

Answer (score 0):

[Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) is what you need. There're numbers of visualization libraries which supports gantt chart.

Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r

Comment: Thank you, will try to address it in a Gantt chart perspective.